# How to tell if an element is a child of another element in JavaScript (no jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

If I have 2 HTML elements, how can I easily tell if 1 is a child of the other?

```
var parent = document.getElementById('shapes');
var child = document.getElementById('star');
```

Is there any kind of function on an element like `child.getParentElement()` that I could compare with like `child.getParentElement() == parent`?

I understand `parent.children` gives me back an array of children, so I suppose I could use a for loop and compare each to `child`. Is there an easier single-function way to do this?

No jQuery or other libraries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the `.parentNode` of the child.

```
if (child.parentNode === parent) {...
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for :), won't let me mark this as answered for 10 more mins though...

Answer (score 2):

There is `parentNode` property within `element`, so you can do following:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('shapes');
var child = document.getElementById('star');

var isChild = false;
var current = child;
while(current = current.parentNode)
{
    if(current == parent)
        isChild = true;
}
```

It will return true if `parent` element is somewhere over `child` element within DOM - not only when it's directly its parent.

Answer (score 1):

If you need only the direct child from parent element, take a look at below example:

```html
<div id="div1">
    Parent
    <div id="div2">
        Child
        <div id="div3-1">
            N-child 1
        </div>
        <div id="div3-2">
            N-child 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn-action" value="Run" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementById("btn-action").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    var div1 = document.getElementById("div1"),
        div2 = document.getElementById("div2"),
        nchild1 = document.getElementById("div3-1"),
        nchild2 = document.getElementById("div3-2");

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
        "<br/>div2 is child of div1? - " + fnIsChild(div1, div2) + 
        "<br/>div3-1 is child of div1? - " + fnIsChild(div1, nchild1) + 
        "<br/>div3-2 is child of div1? - " + fnIsChild(div1, nchild1);
});

function fnIsChild(parentElem, childElem) {
    var childNodes = parentElem.childNodes,
        max = childNodes.length,
        n;
    for(n = 0; n < max; n += 1) {
        if(childNodes[n] === childElem) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use  `child.parentElement`  to get parent.

I also Want to point out you can view all such properties in `chrome web console`

[image]